# How do I check if checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check whether checkbox is checked and background color needs to be changed using  jquery or javascript.

```
<div class="index" id="test">
    <h2>testing</h2>
       <div class="string">
         <ul>
            <li class="nv1">
               <input type="checkbox" value="in1" id="chk1" />
                <div class="checkbox-select">lblstr1</div>
                <div class="checkbox-deselect">lblstr2</div>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS for this...

```
.string li.nv1,
.nv1 .checkbox-select {
 width: 120px;

 }

.nv1 .checkbox-deselect {
  width: 120px;
   background: #8dc63f;
 }
```

Thanks,
 ShailShin

Comment: which element background you need to change?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qc9Qr/ this is the pure css solution

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
   if($("#chk1").is(":checked")){
         $(".checkbox-deselect").css("background" , "red");
   }
   else{
        $(".checkbox-deselect").css("background" , "green");
   }
```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot!, Is there a way to do the switch...case for given html code if multiple list present. Thanks, ShailShin